# Unable to update a state variable twice in same function for showing/hiding loader

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to show a loader when a button is clicked service is invoked and to hide that loader once the data is loaded. But somehow i am not able to achieve this. Pretty sure its a dumb mistake but unfortunately i am not able to locate. Please find below a part of the code.

```
    /* button click function, this function will be carried to a child component, which will invoke once the button in child component is clicked */

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loadingPoints: false
        }
        }

    searchWithChosenFilter = (data) => {

        this.setState(state => {      // THIS IS NOT WORKING
            return {
                ...this.state,
                loadingPoints: true
            }
        })

        Service.someService()
            .then(response => {
                this.setState(state => {   // THIS IS WORKING
                    return {
                        ...this.state,
                        loadingPoints: false
                    }
                });

            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    loadingPoints: false
                });
            })
        }
```

Comment: i am saying because in my code i put a console which prints `this.state` after both the setstate function invocation. Rest assured `this.state` works because i am using an arrow function so don't wry about that. Its just i dnt know how exactly to do both setstate calls. Is it because the event is made in child component is reason behind... Also `prevState` or `preAnything` rule follows in function but i am using class.

Comment: Also this is not a place for trash talk. This is a place where developers join their ideas to build a better solution and not to point fingers and demeaning them. Mind that.

Comment: Fair enough. Reading up on `setState` will clarify all. Best of luck.